# How can I use custom action on vs-upload?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuesax

### 405 Method Not Allowed

- I'm getting this error and my request url is **null** tho i've set the callback
- I've also tried **@action=""** but I got the same result

> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/callback/null

> Request Method: POST

> Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed

```
<vs-upload automatic :action="upload" fileName="file" @on-success="successUpload" />


export default {
 methods:{
  upload (file) {
    this.$store.dispatch('some/callback', file)
  },
  successUpload() {

  }
}
```

### 500 Internal Server Error

- Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined.

> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/upload

> Request Method: POST

> Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error

```
<vs-upload automatic action="/api/upload" fileName="file" @on-success="successUpload" />

export default {
 methods:{
  successUpload() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO .. it redirect to `Route [login] not defined` means you need to add authorisation in  `api/upload`

Comment: @KamleshPaul `api/upload` is inside the middleware. csrf_token is present on the main blade. where do i put the authorization? I have also tried to put headers on vs-upload but no luck :(

Comment: `csrf` and `auth` token is totally difrrent

Answer (score 1):

you need to add [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) to authorisation

i assume you are using [token](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers) based [auth](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication) as you are using `vuejs`

so solution is

```js
 <vs-upload automatic :headers="{'Authorization' : token}" action="/api/upload" fileName="file" @on-success="successUpload" />
```

you need to add `headers="{"Authorization" : token}"`

https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html#automatic
.
you can check here available params